# Trigger an hover event on a part of image (map/area)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to trigger an hover event on a part of image (an area in a map).

Here's the code:

```
<img src="1.jpg" id="image1" width="500px" height="500px" usemap="#map1" />
<map id="map1" height="500" width="500" name="map1">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,10,10" id="area1" />
</map>
```

I want to trigger the event of hovering on #area1 when page loads, but seems like below is working for divs but isn't working on area

```
$( "#area1" ).mouseover();
```

Comment: Try using the map id of #map1

Comment: It works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/5FFrg/